# Category list for the Unity Launcher

Tags: unity

I've looked the official docs [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) and I can't seem to find a list of categories that the Launcher supports anywhere. Is there such a compiled list somewhere so I can quickly review what are my options?

Answer (score 5):

You can choose your custom categories but is not recommended. Instead
is better use [well known categories](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html)

this link is usefull to read:
[Desktop Entry Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/)

this is a copy by link above:

```
|Main Category|Description                                                                   |Notes                                                                 |  
|-------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|  
|AudioVideo   |Application for presenting, creating, or processing multimedia (audio/video)  |                                                                      |
|Audio        |An audio application                                                          |Desktop entry must include AudioVideo as well                         |  
|Video        |A video application                                                           |Desktop entry must include AudioVideo as well                         |  
|Development  |An application for development                                                |                                                                      |    
|Education    |Educational software                                                          |                                                                      |  
|Game         |A game                                                                        |                                                                      |  
|Graphics     |Application for viewing, creating, or processing graphics                     |                                                                      | 
|Network      |Network application such as a web browser                                     |                                                                      |  
|Office       |An office type application                                                    |                                                                      |  
|Science      |Scientific software                                                           |                                                                      |  
|Settings     |Settings applications                                                         |Entries may appear in a separate menu or as part of a "Control Center"|  
|System       |System application, "System Tools" such as say a log viewer or network monitor|                                                                      |  
|Utility      |Small utility application, "Accessories"                                      |                                                                      |  
|-------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Thanks for the tip to Jacob Vlijm.